# How to Print a Cell Landscape in a Portrait Orientation Notebook?

Tags: cells, printing, document-creation

I have a few cells in a report (notebook or CDF) that need to be printed `"Landscape"` where the rest of the report is printed `"Portrait"`. These cells are in different sections/locations of the report.

I found the [`PrintingOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrintingOptions.html) option and its `"PaperOrientation"` setting. There is no information on where to use it so I tried it on `ExpressionCell` with no effect.

```
ExpressionCell[
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1},
  AspectRatio -> 5/10.5, Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> {
     QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[10.5, "Inches"], "DesktopPublishingPoints"],
     Automatic}],
 "Output",
  PrintingOptions -> {"PaperOrientation" -> "Landscape"}]
```

The above cell contains a plot $10.5\times5$ inches. It prints portrait and chops off a portion of the right-hand side of the plot.

I also tried adding page breaks before and after the cell.  However, *Print Preview* still shows all cells printed `"Portrait"`.

The notebook/CDF should print all cases of *File | Print* (also the *File | Save As* PDF case) with these cells in `"Landscape"` and the other cells in `"Portrait"`. The cells cannot be rotated in the report as the reader will not be able to read/interact with them.

Any ideas how to set certain cells to print in specific paper orientations? This would be similar to how you can change page orientations between sections within a Microsoft Word document (I know this is not Word).

Comment: I am not sure if you do much beyond using Rotate.

Comment: Could we have an example of a cell that needs the treatment you ask for?

Comment: @m_goldberg I added a representative cell. It is a plot that is $10.5 \times 5$ inches so needs to be printed `"Landscape"`. However, the rest of the notebook (or CDF) needs to be printed `"Portrait"`.

Comment: I'm running into this issue now too. Were you able to find a solution @Edmund ?