# How to view the print/PDF printable page edge in a Notebook?

Tags: pdf-format, printing, pagelayout

**Motivation:**

I don't normally print or save as PDF notebooks, but when I do, it's annoying to see that some plots exceded the page width as defined in the print configurations.
It would be nice to see in the notebook a mark, probably a line, even if roughly defining the page width.

**Question:**

***What options does Wolfram Mathematica provide to allow the user to be aware of the print/PDF page width while working?***

It would be desirable to have a style or environment that clearly marks the end of the printable region with a line.

Comment: [detailed explanation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125128/5467)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Printout environment

#### 1.1 window menu

In the notebook menu *"Format"*, sub-menu *"Screen Environment"*, it's possible to choose a *"Printout"* environment. There is no line indicating the edge, but thing exceeding the width will not appear.

[image]

#### 1.2 programmatically

Programmatically users can use the option [`PrintingStyleEnvironment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrintingStyleEnvironment.html) or [`ScreenStyleEnvironment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScreenStyleEnvironment.html).

### 2 Ruler

As pointed out by @Hugh, It may help to show the ruler. From [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToToolbars.html).

> The ruler is a toolbar used to set the text margins of selected cells
>   and the indentation of cell names and keywords. The notebook ruler can
>   be added to a notebook by selecting Show Ruler in the Window menu or
>   programmatically by using the notebook option [`WindowToolbars`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowToolbars.html).

#### 2.1 window menu

[image]

#### 2.2 programmatically

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowToolbars -> {"RulerBar"}] (* ON *)

SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowToolbars -> {}] (* OFF *)
```

---

I'm not aware of a way to explicitly show a line marking the end of the printable region in the page itself. Other answers are most welcomed.

Comment: Also go to the Window tab and put up a Toolbar with a  ruler. The ruler has tabs indicating the page width.